# Updating dropdown list in gridview is not working, value is not being updated in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a gridview and a dropdown in one of the rows, I am able to retrieve values from database successfully, but I am not able to update dropdown value when it is changed and updated.

My C# file is:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DropDownList ddList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlstatus");

            DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            ddList.SelectedItem.Text = dr["status"].ToString();
            ddList.SelectedValue = dr["status"].ToString();
            // Response.Write("the selected value is"+ddList.SelectedValue);
            val = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            int id = int.Parse(val);
            //Response.Write(val);
            string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE driver SET status = @status WHERE driverid = @driverid"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", ddList.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driverid", id);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help/guidance please, thanks

Comment: Are the ID and status values what you are expecting? Do you get an error?

Comment: Question is, are you sure you are getting the correct values from the RowDataBound event? also be sure to close the connection after ExecuteNonQuery (even though you are using the using block, which will close/dispose the object, it is still good practice to close the connection immediately after executing your command) Also, what type of database are you using? LocalDB? SQLExpress? Are you attaching the DB in the connectionstring ? Are you overwriting your SDF file on every build?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas can you explain why it is "good practice" to explicitly close the connection when it is in a `using` block?

Comment: @stuartid yes,when i print the vlaues i am getting exact values which i want,i didnt get any error stuart

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas i am using SQL Server,yes i am attaching the db in connection string.Overwriting SDF file,i did not understand that part

Comment: post your connection string - also, how are you checking to see if the data is updated? through code or via SSMS?

Comment: @ Ahmed ilyas my connection string is fine ,as i am able to insert ,update for some other functionalities using this connection string  :    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|customer.mdf;User ID='krishna-PC';Password='';Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True

Comment: I used debug points and what is happening is that ,when Edit button is pressed the above code is executing,but when i make change or press update button this above method is not being called at all.Is there any other event called when Update button is clicked or an event called when drop down list is changed in a grid view,so that i can place the update query in that .

Comment: Why would you expect the [RowDataBound event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) to be hit when you click the Update button or the ddl is changed?

Comment: @BCdotWEB i just found out from different articles,questions and from forums took code from here and there and made some changes ,but i guess this part of putting code in GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) was wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,here is the code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList ddlCurrentDropDownList = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow grdrDropDownRow = ((GridViewRow)ddlCurrentDropDownList.Parent.Parent);
        DropDownList ddList = (DropDownList)grdrDropDownRow.FindControl("ddlstatus");
        statusval = ddList.SelectedValue.ToString();
        Session[statusval] = statusval;    
    }
  protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        string rname = (string)row.Cells[1].Text;


        string ConnectionStringn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE driver SET status=@status WHERE driverid=@driverid"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status",statusval);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driverid",rname);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```